# Line between three divs css, html

Tags: html, css

I'm unsure how to tackle what i'm doing.

[image]

I'm basically trying to achieve the above. I have a `section` tag and a list of `li` tags with a `hr` tag for the line. They overlap poorly though and don't sit/look as smoothly as i'd like.

Html:

```
<section class="navigation">
    <li class="page_nav--one">One</li>
    <hr class="page_nav--line_break" />
    <li class="page_nav--two">Two</li>
    <li class="page_nav--three">Three</li>
</section>
```

and my css looks like :

```
.navigation {
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px 0;
    display: block;

    .page_nav--line_break {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        height: 1px;
        top: -14px;
        border: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        /* margin: 1em 0; */
        padding: 0;
        width: 400px;
        right: 202px;
        z-index: 999999;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10px 85px;
    }

    li:before {
        content: '';
        height: 16px;
        width: 16px;
        background-size: 16px 16px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -23px;
        left: 16px;
        margin: auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    li:nth-child(1):before {
        background: url("trianle_image.png");
    }

    li:nth-child(2):before {
        left: 23px;
        background: url("trianle_image.png");
    }

    li:nth-child(3):before {
        left: 35px;
        background: url("trianle_image.png");
    }
}
```

Is there a better method/way of achieving what i'm after or am I going about it the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use `:after` pseudo elements.

```
<div class="diamond"></div>
<div class="diamond"></div>
<div class="diamond"></div>
```

then the CSS with pseudo elements looks like this:

```
.diamond {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    position:relative:
    float:left;
    margin-right:100px;
}
.diamond:last-of-type {
    margin-right:0;
}
.diamond:after {
    content:""
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:1px;
    background-color:gray;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}
.diamond:last-of-type:after {
    display:none;
}
```

So the theory is that the after element is your line (like you have) and it is as wide as the margin between the two elements, placed exactly where you need it.  Then the last one is hidden.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qxrf2vh7/)

Comment: Cheers man! I'll try this, what does the `:last-of-type` mean/do?

Comment: `:last-of-type` targets the very last element inside of its parent.  So whether it's a `div`, `li`, `p`, whatever, Whichever is the last element in its container will be targeted.  I've added a jsfiddle to show how it works